# How to reference a function within a macro in clojurescirpt?

Tags: clojure, dependencies

I have a macro defined like so in macros.cljh file:

```
(defmacro db-event [event-key params & body]
  `(do
     (re-frame.core/reg-event-db ~event-key
                                 (fn [~'db [_# ~@params]]
                                   (deep-merge ~'db ~@body)))
     (defn ~(symbol event-key) ~params (re-frame.core/dispatch [~event-key ~@params]))))
```

which references a function deep-merge. This macro is defined in the namespace myapp.macros. Yet when I use the macro in a cljs file, I get the error:

```
Use of undeclared Var myapp.macros/deep-merge
```

even though deep-merge is also defined in the myapp.macros namespace

I have the macro required in macros.cljs file like so too:

```
(ns myapp.macros
  (:require-macros [myapp.macros]))
```

I tried adding this to the cljs namespace declaration:

```
  (:require [myapp.macros :refer [deep-merge]])
```

But that gives a circular dependency error. What am I doing wrong in refereeing the deep-merge function?

Answer (score 0):

Macros in ClojureScript are more complicated, and must adhere to a 2-stage compilation process.

See these links for starters, then search out other blog postings & docs as well

- https://clojurescript.org/about/differences#_macros
- https://blog.fikesfarm.com/posts/2016-03-01-clojurescript-macro-sugar.html

In particular, the macro must be **defined** in a `*.cljc` or `*.clj` file, then **used** in the `*.cljs` file.  You can see some examples in action in this template project:

- https://github.com/cloojure/cljs-template

I just checked and it still works, although it uses the old version of Figwheel and has not yet been upgraded to Figwheel-Main (aka Figwheel 2.0).

Comment: But that's not the answer to my question! Also, this doesn't mention cljc file: https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2019/10/12/clojurescript-macros.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define the macro in the macros.clj file with `deep-merge` in macros.cljs. As you’ve seen, you can’t introduce circular dependencies. Your goal is to require the namespace, with the macros. `:require-macros` ensures that if you require the namespace, the macros are included. You should be able to use the macro by requiring the namespace normally:

```clj
(ns myapp.core
  (:require [myapp.macros :as macros]))

(db-event …)
```

An alternative solution, instead of calling `:require-macros` in macros.cljs, is to `:require` the namespace with `:include-macros true`. As an example,

In macros.clj:

```clj
(ns myapp.macros)

(defmacro twice
  [& body]
  `(twice-helper (fn []
                   ~@body)))
```

In macros.cljs:

```clj
(ns myapp.macros)

(defn twice-helper
  [f]
  (f)
  (f))
```

Then we can use the macro in core.cljs:

```clj
(ns myapp.core
  (:require [myapp.macros :as macros :include-macros true]))

(macros/twice (println "hello!"))
```